# vb.net blank data in datatable causing loop to exit, not populating listview

Tags: vb.net, loops, datatable, dataset

I'm using the following code to populate a column in a listview from a dataset which was retrieved using a query in an access db:

```
    For Each field As DataRow In dt.Rows()
        If field Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("there's nothing here")
        End If

        ListViewBatchResults.Items.Add(field(3))

    Next
```

The problem is, as soon as a blank field is encountered, the loop exits and the list view isn't finished being populated, so any data after the first blank field which was encountered isn't being shown.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: No - nothing! it just runs the project, the form is displayed and the data is shown as per the data in the db to the point where the first blank field is encountered.

Comment: You are checking to see if the dataRow is Nothing (which, in this case, there is something), but not checking if the field column is Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if value is `null` before adding, like:

```
 If (Not IsDBNull(field(3))) Then
     Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(field(3).ToString())
     lvwItem.SubItems.Add(field(4).ToString())
 End If
```

You could probably also try to check if it is `null` or `empty` like:

```
 If (Not IsDBNull(field(3))) Then
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(field(3))) Then
       Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(field(3).ToString())
       lvwItem.SubItems.Add(field(4).ToString())
    End If
 End If
```

Comment: That code just seems to duplicate the data into the first column of the listview:

data1
data1
data2
data2
data3
data3

etc... then you just get the same issue - it stops at the field which contains no data :(

Comment: How many columns does your `listview` have? Because if it's more than one you could use `Subitems.Add` aside from `Items.Add`.

Comment: 8 columns, I'm trying to get the listview to populate each column as per the columns in the database query, but that's another story...

Comment: When I do SubItems.Add I just get this error:

'SubItems' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'

Comment: Thanks Edper, still doesn't work however - just doesn't want to populate the list view if it encounters a blank field :(